# Is it possible to have a RecyclerView as the header of a ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a ListView with a header that is a horizontally scrolling RecyclerView, but am having some problems.

Here is the code of the Fragment in which I am trying to create this scenario:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.viewLayoutResId = isGrid ? R.layout.fragment_deals_grid : R.layout.fragment_deals_list;
    this.listResId = isGrid ? R.id.deal_grid : R.id.deal_list;

    View view = inflater.inflate(viewLayoutResId, container, false);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.deal_progress);

    mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(listResId);

    //HEADER CREATION HERE
    RecyclerView header = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deals_display_header, null);

    header.setAdapter(new DealsDisplayCategoriesAdapter(Deal.CATEGORIES));
    header.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    header.setHasFixedSize(true);

    if(mListView instanceof ListView) {
        ListView listView = (ListView) mListView;

        listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
    }else if(mListView instanceof GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter) {
        GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter gridView = (GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter) mListView;

        gridView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
    }else{
        Log.v("DEALDISPLAY", "no header :: "+mListView);
    }

    ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) mListView).setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return view;
}
```

The problem is simply that the RecyclerView header does not show up. It just appears empty.

I have tested a few cases in an attempt to narrow down where the problem might be:

- Adding a non-recyclerview header to the AbsListView: This works - The header appears as intended (on both grid and list)
- Inflating the RecyclerView as its own Fragment - in the exact same way as done here: This works - The RecyclerView displays a populated horizontal list as intended

In summary, adding a header that isn't a RecyclerView works, so the header can't be the problem. Inflating the RecyclerView elsewhere works, so the RecyclerView can't be the problem.

What am I doing wrong? Is what I am trying to do even possible?

EDIT:

fragment_deals_display_header.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/deals_display_header_recycler">


</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Show your `fragment_deals_display_header `

Comment: Try adding LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT to your RecyclerView, it may seems it's in WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: @NaviRamyle If something was wrong with the LayoutParams, would it not show when I inflated the recyclerview outside of the listview?

Comment: @mr.icetea let me recreate the problem, i'm curious what's wrong with it

Comment: you'll have to hardcode the height of the recyclerview as it does not support wrap_content

Comment: @k0sh Is the height of the RecyclerView not match_parent - defined in the xml? Or should match_parent be defined in the LayoutManager?

Comment: @grimrader22 k0sh is right, you have to hardcode the height, `header.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100))`